# TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Can someone help me?

```
if (retornar != false) return
const textChannels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type === 'text');
if (!textChannels.every(channel => channel.permissionOverwrites.get(mudo))) {
    textChannels.forEach(async (channel) => {
        await channel.updateOverwrite(mudo,
            { SEND_MESSAGES: false, ADD_REACTIONS: false })
    }
}
```

return TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role.

Comment: what is `retornar`? And what line does the error reference?

Comment: `mudo` is not a User or Role